# Buscar valor especifico en QList

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo una lista en qt

```
QList<double> list;
```

cuya lista contiene muchos valores del tipo double, por ejemplo:

- (2.41043, 3.6002, 7.41904, 6.41041, 7.59567, 1.80702)

como puedo recorrer esa lista y encontrar entre todos los valores el valor más cercano al 0? y que me retorne la posición en la que se encuentra ese valor en la lista?

Comment: Esos números no son enteros. ¿Te refieres a `double`?

Comment: Era double, perdón. Tengo varias maneras en mente de realizarlo, pero estaba buscando alguna más eficiente a las que tengo pensada. Con for no he podido, soy nuevo en esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías recorrer la lista con iteradores, e ir guardando el mínimo, el código sería:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QList<double> list;
    list.append(2.410430);
    list.append(3.6002);
    list.append(7.41904);
    list.append(6.41041);
    list.append(7.59567);
    list.append(1.80702);

    if(!list.isEmpty())
    {
        int idx;
        double min;
        int index;
        QList<double>::const_iterator it = list.begin();

        min = *it;      // Obtener el primer valor del iterador
        index = 0;      // Primer indice

        for(it++, idx = 1; it != list.end(); it++, idx++)
        {
            if(*it < min)       // Comprobar si el actual valor es mayor al mímimo
            {
                // Si es así ...
                // asignar min con el valor actual del iterador
                // y asignar el index con el índice de valor actual del iterador
                min = *it;
                index = idx;
            }
        }
        qDebug("min: %f", min); // Imprimir el mínimo valor encontrado
        qDebug("index: %d", index); // Imprimir el índice del mínimo valor encontrado
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas :D

Comment: @I.Plumb ahí edité pasa usarlo con double

Comment: Si la lista contiene valores negativos, se quedará con el valor más pequeño, no con el más cercano a 0.

Comment: @GermánMartínez Muchas Gracias! PaperBirdMaster, por suerte la lista nunca tendrá negativos.

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres obtener el valor más cercano al 0, deberás tener en cuenta que te puedes acercar a 0 desde -∞ y desde +∞.

Dado que [la propia documentación de Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) especifica que `QList` es compatible con la interfaz estándar de contenedores C++:

> Like the other container classes, QList provides Java-style iterators (QListIterator and QMutableListIterator) and STL-style iterators (QList::const_iterator and QList::iterator).

Puedes usar la función [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) de la cabecera [`<algoritm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
auto min = std::min_element(list.begin(), list.end(),
                             [](auto &a, auto &b){ return std::abs(a) < std::abs(b); });
```

Al comparar contra el valor absoluto ([`std::abs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs)) en lugar de comparar por valor mínimo, detectaras la distancia hacia 0 (Puedes ver un ejemplo de uso en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DydXJWcb3Rt8Z3kA)).

El código anterior devuelve un iterador al elemento más cercano a 0, para saber su posición, usa [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
auto posicion = std::distance(list.begin(), min);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu sabiduría!

Comment: @Trauma se me pasó lo de la posición... pero no se para qué la querría nadie teniendo el iterador :)